# Call Custom REST API from Confluence

Tags: javascript, c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, confluence

I have created and deployed my own webservice (WCF C#). I would like to call it using JavaScript, get data and populate a Chart.

Here is the code I pasted inside of a confluence *[HTML macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/html-macro-38273085.html)*:

```
<script>
function fun() 
{
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "http://mydomain:port/MyService.svc/testRest",
        data: "m=aa",
        processData: true,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
             console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (e) {
             console.log('error ' + e.status + ' ' + e.responseText);
         }
      });
 }

 var x =  fun();
 console.log(x);
</script>
```

The error I receive via developer console on Google Chrome (F12):

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myconfluencesite.com/mypage' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://mydomain:port/MyService.svc/testRest?m=aa'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I have already *[whitelisted](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-the-whitelist-381255821.html)* the service URL *http://mydomain:port/MyService.svc/testRest*. Assuming I activate SSL on my domain, would that fix the issue? Are there better methods?

The main idea is to load/populate tables/charts with external data. So I first started with my own service which returns a JSON structure. If that works, I can then use that structure to populate/load a HighCharts component for example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change `http://mydomain:port/MyService.svc/testRest` to `https://mydomain:port/MyService.svc/testRest`.  Google Chrome, rightly, does not like that you have a page served through https which then calls a service using http.  So, yes, activating SSL **and using it** will fix the issue.  I would even say that no service should ever use a non-secure channel.  Have your service **require** ssl.

Comment: I suspect [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) will also come into play

Comment: @stuartd - it might, once he gets past the mixed content error, but that would be a separate question.